# Changing text of an element with jQuery with click event. It changes back an instant later

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a Magic 8 Ball page and every time I click the submit button on my page the text in my heading #eightBallAnswer changes to one of my random answers for a fraction of a second then changes back to the original text in my HTML. I've tried this in multiple browsers. Some insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function() {

        //List of possible responses
        var response = ["Ask again later…", "Yes", "No", "It appears so", "Reply is hazy, please try again", "Yes, definitely", "What is it you really want to know?", "Outlook is good", "My sources say no", "Signs point to yes", "Don't count on it", "Cannot predict now", "As I see it, yes", "Better not tell you now", "Concentrate and ask again"];

        //generate a random number between 0-14
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);

        //Present random answer
        $("#eightBallAnswer").text(response[randomNumber]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't use a `<form>` element. If you have a submit button inside a form then clicking it will submit the form, which will reload the page. Or you could cancel the default behaviour of the button from within your event handler.

Comment: Thank you! This worked too and I went with your solution for simplicity. Turns out the HTML5 validates just fine too with inputs not contained by a form tag. Awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's cause your form is submitting and the page refreshing :)

Use `event.preventDefault()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function( event ) {

        event.preventefault();

        //List of possible responses
        var response = ["Ask again later…", "Yes", "No", "It appears so", "Reply is hazy, please try again", "Yes, definitely", "What is it you really want to know?", "Outlook is good", "My sources say no", "Signs point to yes", "Don't count on it", "Cannot predict now", "As I see it, yes", "Better not tell you now", "Concentrate and ask again"];

        //generate a random number between 0-14
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);

        //Present random answer
        $("#eightBallAnswer").text(response[randomNumber]);
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked, @nnnnnn was also right in that simply removing the form tag from my html would prevent the page from refreshing. Thanks for helping a newbie out guys!